# Android no internet connection WITH uses permissions correct

Tags: java, android, permissions

I'm writing my first app on android.

While testing my jdbc connection on PC it's Ok, but on device it fails.
I've made a check for internet

```js
   public static boolean isInternetAvailable() {
        try {
            InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("google.com"); 
            return !ipAddr.equals("");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

On PC (the same wifi network) it returns `True` and jdbc connects, but on android SDK 23 (Meizu pro6 device) it returns `False`

My Manifest:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ibox.xobicity" >


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_app_xobi"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/icon_app_xobi"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I've spend 3 hours of googling with no solution. 
Thanks everybody in advance and sorry for my English.

Comment: Is your AVD configured to emulate the same SDK as your physical device?

Comment: Hello. It was not. After your question I have tried to use different virtual devices and tried to use compile version the same as my physical device. (SKD 23 android 6.0) The same result. I even tried to reinstall Studio to another computer and rebuild all from beginning.

Comment: So after you changed your virtual device to SDK 23(the same as your physical device), the virtual device still worked, and the physical device did not?

Comment: Thank you for one more response. All: physical skd 23, virtual 23, 25 didn't work = internet connection (as described above) tells me false and jdbc connection fails too